# Change from static array to vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

here's my code:

```
vector<int> Edge[1000000]; //size of array must be very high

scanf("%d%d",&N,&M );
//N = size of workable index numbers for Edge
for( i=1;i<=M;i++){

    scanf("%d%d",&u,&v );
    Edge[u].push_back( v );
}
```

But as you can see, it's a static array of vectors.
If i change it to this:

```
vector<vector<int>> Edge;
```

How can i do that for cycle and pushback? I need to create a vector of N+1 size and each position is also a vector.

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> Edge(100000);` or `vector<vector<int>> Edge; Edge.resize(100000);`

Comment: I need to initialize after declation, because it's a global variable

Comment: It is still valid even if the variable is global.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know the size yet when you declare the variable?

Comment: It's exactly that, thanks

Comment: No, i don't know the size yet, I do a scanf to know the size, now it's all working well

Comment: Then use `vector<vector<int>> Edge(N);` or `vector<vector<int>> Edge; Edge.resize(N);`

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a vector of N+1 size and each position is also a vector.

Considering that you know the size of the external container at compile time, you can also use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to store the vectors:

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, N + 1> Edge;
```

If you don't know the size at compile time, you could use:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Edge;
```

but as a general rule of thumb, tend to avoid vectors of vectors, as they don't usually work nicely.

Comment: I agreed until this: "tend to avoid vectors of vectors, as they don't usually work nicely".

Comment: @PaulDraper, it would probably be a good idea to say the reason as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct vectors of a given size by passing an int to their constructor. Then afterwards you can use a loop to initialize the subvectors.

```
int size;
vector<vector<int>> Edge(size); //Initializes Outer Array to have 'size' elements

for(auto i:Edge)
{
    // i is a vector within Edge
}
```

The advantage is that you don't have to push back. If you still wanted to push_back in order (not have to track an iterator/int) you could use vector.reserve() instead.